# Prblem with find_all in BeautifulSoup4

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, findall

I want to get information on the following [website](https://www.boekenprijs.be/uitgebreid-zoeken?zoek=&veld=all&gbpstartdatumvan=&gbpstartdatumtotenmet=&gbpeinddatumvan=01/04/2024&gbpeinddatumtotenmet=12/08/2024&_token=FAoSCCoUK-SPrL-ktj4MtsVBv3L4K-FaH3jxSo259D0&page=9). I need book titles, codes, prices, etc. For instance, let's concentrate on ISBN codes. I want to find in the html any piece of text that has the "ISBN" word.

My code is the following:

```py
url_0 = 'https://www.boekenprijs.be/uitgebreid-zoeken?zoek=&veld=all&gbpstartdatumvan=&gbpstartdatumtotenmet=&gbpeinddatumvan=01/04/2024&gbpeinddatumtotenmet=12/08/2024&_token=FAoSCCoUK-SPrL-ktj4MtsVBv3L4K-FaH3jxSo259D0&page=1'

result = requests.get(url)

doc = BeautifulSoup(result.text, "html.parser")

aux = doc.find_all(string="ISBN")
```

My problem here is that my outcome aux is empty, I cannot find anything with ISBN, but looking at the html I do see this word.

Comment: `string="ISBN"` looks for an exact match. Try `string=re.compile('ISBN')` to perform a partial match.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may not be the best way, But it might be an alternative I'am using lambda to filter tag div where "ISBN" text inside

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.boekenprijs.be/uitgebreid-zoeken?zoek=&veld=all&gbpstartdatumvan=&gbpstartdatumtotenmet=&gbpeinddatumvan=01/04/2024&gbpeinddatumtotenmet=12/08/2024&_token=FAoSCCoUK-SPrL-ktj4MtsVBv3L4K-FaH3jxSo259D0&page=1'
result = requests.get(url)
doc = BeautifulSoup(result.text, "html.parser")
# Find elements ISBN
aux = doc.find_all(lambda tag: tag.name == 'div' and "ISBN" in tag.text)
for element in aux:
    print(element.text)
```

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the comment, you can use `re` module to search for strings:

```py
import re

import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www.boekenprijs.be/uitgebreid-zoeken?zoek=&veld=all&gbpstartdatumvan=&gbpstartdatumtotenmet=&gbpeinddatumvan=01/04/2024&gbpeinddatumtotenmet=12/08/2024&_token=FAoSCCoUK-SPrL-ktj4MtsVBv3L4K-FaH3jxSo259D0&page=1"
result = requests.get(url)

doc = BeautifulSoup(result.text, "html.parser")
aux = doc.find_all(string=re.compile("ISBN"))

print(aux)
```

Prints:

```
['\n                        ISBN ', '\n                        ISBN ', '\n                        ISBN ', '\n                        ISBN ', '\n                        ISBN ', '\n                        ISBN ', '\n                        ISBN ', '\n                        ISBN ', '\n                        ISBN ', '\n                        ISBN ']
```

---

But more useful will be searching for HTML tags which contain the string "ISBN":

```py
for tag in doc.select(':-soup-contains-own("ISBN")'):
    print(tag.prettify())
```

Prints:

```html
...

<div class="col-12 col-md-4 text-right">
 <strong>
  <span class="price">
   € 24.95
  </span>
 </strong>
 <br/>
 Van
 <strong>
  01-10-2023
 </strong>
 t.e.m.
 <strong>
  01-04-2024
 </strong>
 <br/>
 ISBN
 <strong>
  9789090374475
 </strong>
 <br/>
</div>

...
```

Comment: Thank you! The first option works better if I search instead for "978", since all codes start with this numbers. Really helpful!